# Any way to use rrule going backwards

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-dateutil, rrule

Is there any way to run `dateutils.rrule.rrule` going back in time? For example, I would like

```
[dt.datetime(2014, 8, 29, 0, 0), 
 dt.datetime(2014, 9, 5, 0, 0), 
 dt.datetime(2014, 9, 12, 0, 0), 
 dt.datetime(2014, 9, 19, 0, 0), 
 dt.datetime(2014, 9, 26, 0, 0)]
```

in this example:

```
import datetime as dt
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, WEEKLY

date0 = dt.datetime(2014, 10, 3)
date1 = dt.datetime(2014, 8, 26)

rrule(WEEKLY, dtstart=date0).between(date0, date1)
```

But, this gives me an empty list...

**Insert sad, frowny face**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import datetime as dt
import dateutil.rrule as RR

date0 = dt.datetime(2014, 10, 3)
date1 = dt.datetime(2014, 8, 26)

start = min([date0, date1])
end = max([date0, date1])
dow = RR.weekday(date0.weekday())
print(RR.rrule(RR.WEEKLY, byweekday=dow, dtstart=start).between(start, end))
```

yields

```
[datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 29, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 5, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 12, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 19, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 26, 0, 0)]
```

I don't think there is a way to define an rrule with `dtstart=date0` which generates dates *before* `date0`. You must use the earlier date. Moreover, `between(a, b)` must be called with `a <= b`, or else the result will be empty.

Comment: Hmmm, ok, that makes sense. But, if I wanted the dates between `date0 = dt.datetime(2014, 10, 6)` and `date1 = dt.datetime(2014, 8, 26)` such that it gave `[..., (2014, 9, 29)]`... can rrule tell which day the end date is? Instead of it using the start day? I don't want to hard code friday in there :-/

Comment: 2014-8-26 is a Tuesday, 2014-10-6 is a Monday. So I think you have to tell `rrule` that you want Fridays.

Comment: Ok, I mean, I don't want just fridays. I will probably do something like `dow = {0: RR.MO, 1: RR.TU, 2: RR.WE, 3: RR.TH, 4: RR.FR, 5: RR.SA, 6:RR.SU};` and then `byweekday=dow[date0.weekday()]` or something. You can update your answer with this, and I will accept it as satisfactory. :) Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case, you could use `dow = RR.weekday(date0.weekday())`.